# Java - client-server clock

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, client, server

I'm kind of stuck on one issue. I got a client-server app in Java, where multiple clients can connect to a server. Now I have a cyclic operation, which is getting the current time (corresponding to my ClockTask on the server side). But I don't really know how do I transmit this time data to all connected clients. It should be done somehow by ObjectOutputStream I guess, but it would be nice if someone could clue me in.

Here's my server code, together with thread running a client connection:

```
 public class Server {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        boolean listeningSocket = true;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 11111");
        }

        while(listeningSocket){
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected!");
            ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket);
            ct.start();

        }
        serverSocket.close();       
    }
}
```

Connect thread:

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

private Socket socket = null;


public ConnectThread(Socket socket) {

super("ConnectThread");
this.socket = socket;
```

}

```
@Override
public void run(){
ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = null;
try {
    System.out.println("check");
    serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("check");
    serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    serverOutputStream.writeInt(42);
    System.out.println("check");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    try {
        serverOutputStream.close();
        serverInputStream.close();              
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

}
```

and the client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] arg) {


Socket socketConnection = null;
ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream clientInputStream = null;
        try {

    socketConnection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 11111);

    clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            socketConnection.getOutputStream());
    clientInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
            socketConnection.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("check");
    System.out.println(clientInputStream.readInt()); // HERE'S WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The following exception has occured and was caught:");
    System.out.println(e);
}

finally{
    try {
        clientOutputStream.close();
        clientInputStream.close();
        socketConnection.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
}
```

Clock task:

```
public class ClockTask extends TimerTask {


@Override
public void run() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
    //some object output stream here??
}

}
```

Comment: Why use `Serializable` when so many (more convenient|easier to user|less buggy)[1] RPC protocols exist? [1] pick your choice; generally, any RPC-able protocol over the network obey at least two of the aforementioned characteristics

Comment: Can you try `serverOutputStream.flush()` and then a slight delay after `serverOutputStream.writeInt(42);`, so that the client will get a chance to consume the response before the server closes the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest sending a Calendar object as it is a *very* expensive object using around 2900 bytes.  Instead you could send a long value over a DataOutputStream which would use 8 bytes.

Note: you would need to correct for the latency between the client and the server otherwise the time will be always delayed.

A simple way to address this is for the client to send a message to the server with a timestamp as  long, the server responds with it's own time stamp and you can assume that the delay is half the round trip time.  You can then apply an EWMA (Exponentially Weighted Moving Average) to get a reason average of the difference in the clock on the server and the client.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking about entire calendar either, more like simply sending the date alone. But if I try to do it using simply OOS, I get lots of 'socket closed errors' and the thing gets messy.

Comment: @user4359659 You may find that Data Streams are far simpler. Less magic going on. Just plain primitives being sent.